# Login verification with React, redux and react-redux-router : the proper way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a little question about react, redux and react-redux-router.

This is pretty simple but I can't figure out what is the best way to handle this so let's go.

I'm working on a simple app with a loggin screen and some pages with restrected access to auth users.

Here is my router :

```
   <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
         <Route path={Config.baseUrl} component={App}>
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            <Route component={Administration}>
               <IndexRoute component={Statistics} />
               <Route path="page2" component={p2} />
            </Route>
         </Route>
      </Router>
   </Provider>
```

I want to redirect all no-logged users to the logging page (/login) if they try to reach any pages in `<Route component={Administration}>`.

So what is the best way to achieve that ? I can use `componentWillMount` on every sub-components but I'm sure that's not a good idea :). I've also tried to find a hook on my `Administration` component but nothing interested.

Any advices ?

Sub question : I use `dispatch(routeActions.push())` to navigate between pages. this works fine. But if the landing page (first load) is something else than '/', a 404 is throwed. I **have** to go to '/' first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux and create abstract component AuthorizedViewComponent, which would check user status and redirect all unlogged user to /login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So in my case (for example :)) the Administration component will extends AuthorizedViewComponent and on the willMount of that new component, I will do my verification stuff ?

Comment: @Armelias yes i would do this like that. You can also add some methods like `getRequiredRole() {}` or  `isUserAllowed(user) {}` in extending components, but keep redirect logic in abstract one.